# how to efficiently call github api to extract real names of multiple repo contributors

Tags: r, json, github

I would like to fetch the real names of all the contributors to a list of github repos.  I can do it but it takes a series of looping calls to the github API.  If I want to do, say the top 100 R packages, my approach would take 2100 calls to the API(assuming 20 contributors per repo).  If I undersestimate the number of contributors I might hit the rate limits for authorized users. I would like to know if there is an approach that requires fewer calls to the API.  Below is the what I think is the "hard" way to do it. This example just gets one contributor from one repo, for illustration, with no iterating through lists.

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

#this would actually be a list of multiple repos
repo_name <- "dplyr"
# we don't know the github username associated with the package so construct a search
# to get the most likely candidate
search_url <- paste0("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=",
                     repo_name,
                     ".%20is:name+language:r&sort=stars&order=desc")


# first api call.  would need to would need to loop/map/apply over multiple contributors repo names
all_repos<-jsonlite::read_json(search_url,simplifyVector = TRUE)
# assume first repo is target.  Hope so.
target_repo<-all_repos$items$full_name[1]
search_url <- paste0("https://api.github.com/repos/",
                     target_repo,
                     "/contributors")
#second api call
contributors <- jsonlite::read_json(search_url,simplifyVector = TRUE)

#third api call. would need to loop/map/apply over multiple contributors
real_name <- jsonlite::read_json(contributors$url[1])$name
real_name
#> [1] "Romain François"
```

Thank you.

Comment: The only improvements to your code I can think of are 1) you can `target_repo<-all_repos$items[all_repos$items$name == repo_name,]` and 2) you can `target_repo$contributors_url` in your second API call. But I cannot find a way to reduce the number of API calls.